# How to solve simple wp simple ajax chat caching problem

Tags: cache

i have a frustrating problem with simple ajax chat wordpress plugin. When am trying to create a page with a livechat shorcode and i also need to use cache. But when i enable cache the ajax live function of the chat does not work. Does anyone has any suggestions?
i use lightspeeed cache.

Comment: Can you work out exactly what's going wrong? Do you get any errors in your browser's debug console? Does it not load the chat script, or are some of the calls that the chat system makes back to your server cached? You could make sure they're excluded from the cache setup. Or if it's something else you should probably talk to the authors of the chat shortcode for advice, as they'll know how their systems work and how it would interact with caching.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a solution but I have not tested it.

go to: wp-admin/admin.php?page=litespeed-cache#excludes

Or navigate litespeed->cache->excludes

```
<IfModule LiteSpeed>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/filename\.php
 RewriteRule .* - [E=cache-control:no-cache]
</IfModule>
```

replace filename with the plugin filename.

Comment: file name is simple-ajax-chat.php so i put this on lighspeed cache url excludes                                          <IfModule LiteSpeed>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^simple-ajax-chat.php
RewriteRule .* - [E=cache-control:no-cache]
</IfModule>                 is that corrent?  It does not seem to work